# How to reuse file pattern in .gitignore in bash/zsh?

Tags: bash, files, find, zsh, wildcards

Here is the content of the `.gitignore`

```
cron.yaml
build
target
webview
*.pyc
*.sublime-workspace
.idea
*.rej
.coverage
app/tools/temp_*.py
app/tools/*/temp_*.py
```

I am currently iteraring files in a local folder by this script:

```
find . -type f | grep -v -E "(.idea|.git)" | while read file
do
  # Do something with $file
done
```

I want to further filter this `$file` variable if it matches the pattern in the `.gitignore`. Is there any existing utilities or bash builtin that can understand these file patterns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be able to use `grep`'s `-f` aka (`--file`) option, with process substitution to "regexify" some of the patterns.  For example:

```sh
find . -type f | grep -Ev '(\.idea|\.git)' | 
    grep -v -f <(sed 's/\([.|]\)/\\\1/g; s/\?/./g ; s/\*/.*/g' .gitignore) | 
    while IFS= read -r file ; do 
      # Do something with "$file"
    done
```

Comment: I got a syntax error `./sync_and_build.sh: line 30: syntax error near unexpected token \`('
./sync_and_build.sh: line 30: \`    grep -v -f <(sed 's/\([.|]\)/\\\1/g; s/\?/./g ; s/\*/.*/g' .gitignore) |'`    Very strange. Not sure where the backtick comes from

Comment: what shell are you using?

Comment: If I use `zsh` it is all good. Thx.

Comment: Process Substitution (`<( ... )`) isn't posix, but is fairly common.  supported by bash and ksh88/ksh93 and zsh (but not bash in `--posix` mode, e.g. when called as `#!/bin/sh` instead of `#!/bin/bash`). see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution

Comment: btw, the backticks are GNU's dumb idea of being "clever" with quotes.  damned annoying.  gnu stuff, incl. bash, often uses non-matching `\`` and `'` to quote errors.

Comment: `#!/bin/sh` is exactly what happened! Cheers